# Retry only it- and afterEach-block if something fails in afterEach-block

Tags: cypress

I run my tests with `retry`-option. If something went wrong in an `afterEach`-block then only the `it`-block and the `afterEach`-block is retrying but not the `beforeEach`-block. This is curios behavior in my point of view. So is it a bug or a willful behavior?

P.S.: I'm using Cypress 7.7

Comment: Are you applying the retires globally or with `describe()` or with `it()` ?

Comment: globally in my case

Answer (score 1):

Using a simplified test I get the `beforeEach()` executing on retry.

```js
let retry = 0;

describe('', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    console.log('beforeEach', retry)
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    console.log('afterEach', retry)
    retry = retry +1;
    if (retry === 1) {
      console.log('failing')
      throw 'failed in afterEach'
    }
  })

  it('test1', () => {
    console.log('test1', retry)
    expect(true).to.eq(true)
  })

  it('test2', () => {
    console.log('test2', retry)
    expect(true).to.eq(true)
  })
})
```

Console logs

```
beforeEach 0  
test1 0  
afterEach 0  
failing                // first afterEach fails
beforeEach 1           // retry attempt 
test1 1  
afterEach 1  
beforeEach 2  
test2 2  
afterEach 2
```

Can you add details that might affect this result?

Answer (score 0):

You can find details [Cypress Test Retries](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries#Introduction)

When each test is run again, the following hooks will be re-run also:
beforeEach
afterEach

**However, failures in before and after hooks will not trigger a retry.**

Comment: Then it is a bug. As described a failure within the afterEach-Block repeats only the it-block and then the afterEach-block but the beforeEach-block is not repeated.